# Change overridden member to async

Tags: c#, async-await

I am overriding a method in a base class library.  However, inside my overridden implementation I am using the new HttpClient which is all based on async methods.  I therefore have to mark my method as async, which means that I need to change the return parameter of the method from string to Task.  The compiler however gives an error: "The return type must be 'string' to match overridden member ...."

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual string GetName()
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public class MyClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override async Task<string> GetName()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = response.Content;

                return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Of course the obvious solution would be to change the return type of GetName() in BaseClass to Task<string>, but I have no control over BaseClass as it is an external library;

My current solution is to use the HttpClient classes in a synchronous fashion, i.e. change MyClass as follows:

```
    public class MyClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override string GetName()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync("");
            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = response.Result.Content;

                return responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync()
                                                       .Result;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no good solution (this violates LSP).  Can you create an async wrapper?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a good solution here. There is no way to `override` a non-async method with an async one.  I think your best bet is to have an `async` non-override method and call into that from the non-async one:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass 
{
    public override string GetName() 
    {
        return GetNameAsync().Value;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetNameAsync() 
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that this can cause problems though. If the original code didn't expect for any `async` code to be executing introducing this pattern could break expectations. I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: Isn't this solution a deadlock waiting to happen?

Comment: @G.Stoynev yes that's definitely possible. As i indicated this is a problematic solution and something I would avoid at all possible.

Comment: Thank you @JaredPar.  I understand that it is problematic and will tread carefully :)

Comment: @G.Stoynev You'd need to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to any `await` calls, yes.

Comment: "There is no way to override a non-async method with an async one." - Is it always true? I think (and my experiments seem to confirm that) it's possible when the overriden method returns awaitable type.
So, I guess more precise statement would be "There is now way to override a non-async method with an async one, unless it returns void/Task/Task<TResult>." It doesn't matter in this specific case, but I ended up here wondering if it's possible to override non-async Task methods as async Task methods, which seems to be true. ;)

Comment: If you're worried about deadlock, you're probably in Winforms.  Therefore, I'd recommend a hackish yet workable solution of kicking off a winforms timer and handling the tick event asynchronously, i.e. run your async code from within the timer tick.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is not causing a deadlock since it is likely to have `ConfigureAwait(false)` within.

To prevent a deadlock, you could use one of the following methods:

```
public static T GetResult<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    var httpContext = HttpContext.Context;

    var proxyTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        HttpContext.Context = httpContext;
        return func();
    });

    return proxyTask.Result;
}

// or

public static T GetResult<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(null);

    var task = func();

    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(syncContext);

    return task.Result;
}
```

This way you would call

```
public override string GetName()
{
    ...
    return GetResult(() => responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync());
    ...
}
```

The former has a performance overhead by spawning a new thread, while the latter suffers from breaking `SynchronizationContext` flow, which makes any context bound to it unavailable in the task being called, e.g. `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score -4):

I've also had this problem, and the solution was using an interface, in which 'async' isn't part of the method's signature.

```
public abstract class Base : IInvokable {
    /* Other properties ... */

    public virtual async Task Invoke() {
        /*...*/
    }
}

public interface IInvokable {
    Task Invoke();
}

public class Derived 
{
    public override async Task Invoke() {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: OP states _"Of course the obvious solution would be to change the return type of GetName() in BaseClass to Task<string>, but **I have no control over BaseClass as it is an external library**"_